# NodeJs server deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have deployed my NodeJS server on heroku( followed their tutorial). The procfile file is good because it runs locally. After pushing it on heroku git I have got a link to it. I saw the logs by entering the command :"heroku logs --tail" and the logs said that the server started successfully. But I do not understand how can I access specific paths like : http://localhost:300/auth/login if the heroku urls is https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com. It's my first server deployment. Thank you for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it! I was specifying the port 3000 for the server. But heroku doesn't need it. So instead of it I did something like this:

```
              server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If setup correctly, `http://localhost:300/auth/login` would be accessible by using `https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/auth/login`

Comment: I tried it and nothing. In my package.json i have                          "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/my-gitlab-account.git"
  }. Do I have to put the heroku account?

Comment: you shouldnt need to reference the heroku account anywhere. do you have an index.html page in the root of the project?

Comment: I have index.js. It is a server API , it does not use html.

Comment: if i were you, create a basic index.html file, push it to the root heroku git and see if you can access that page via a web browser, if you cant then something might not be set up right

Answer (score 0):

What does heroku logs --tail say after you try https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/auth/login?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using express, you probably need something like:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 300);
```

Comment: I am using NodeJS with koa-server and typeScript